# How can I make this script run faster?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, tabula

So, I am using tabula to scrub a ton of pdf reports.
For anonimity sake lets assume these reports are about shoes.

-I have a root folder where each shoe report has a folder named SHR-some random number.

----Inside there will be a pdf file that is the actual report.

---------This report contains tables, some of which I must extract and compile into one big summary table and write to a csv file.

I put together the below script that just does the job thanks to stack overflow. I am not a software developer by profession. Currently it takes a little over one minute to process one pdf file.

How can I make it go faster (if possible). I have written a comment for what each line is doing.

```
import tabula as tb
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
import csv
import glob
import os
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

dt=datetime.now() #get current timestamp
timestamp=dt.strftime("%d-%b-%Y (%H-%M)") #format the timestamp string
resultfolder=r"C:/Users/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Analysis_results" #this is the root directory to store all result folders and files

csvpath= resultfolder + '/' + datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S') #define a path for a new folder to be created with timestamp in foldername, everytime this script runs
os.makedirs(csvpath) #make the new folder
path = Path(csvpath) #make the new result subfolder path
fpath= (path / timestamp ).with_suffix('.csv') #make a filepath for a csv file with timestamp in its name
f_public = r"//networkdrive/folder/folder1/folder2" #this is the root folder for all my pdf reports
os.chdir(f_public) #change to the target pdf reports root folder
dbase=pd.DataFrame() # I use this dataframe to store the extracted rows
dbase= dbase.assign(ColA=['Shoe manufacturer','Shoe name','Shoe type','Shoe type','Shoe size','Date code', 'ShoeCode', 'ShoeLink']) # define the first column and name it ColA
unreadcount=0 #counter for pdf files throwing exception while reading
unreadlist=[] #list of unreadable pdf files
ShoeCode=[] #list of current shoe reportcode
ShoeFileName=[] # list of current shoe report file name

for bfr in glob.glob('SHR-*'): # go through folders sarting SHR- in this root folder since all shoe reports are named SHR-something
    try:
        ShoeCode.append(bfr) #append the shoe report code to list
        pdfpath = f_public + '/'+ bfr # figure out path to the folder of this shoe report - which will have actual shoe report pdf file inside 
        os.chdir(pdfpath) #go inside report folder
        file = [f for  f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f) and f.endswith('.pdf')] #find the file with pdf extension int his folder
        ShoeFileName.append(file[0]) # add file nme to list
        pdffile=pdfpath + '/'+ file[0] # figure out pdf file path
        tables = tb.read_pdf(pdffile, pages="all", pandas_options={'header': None}) # extract all tables in pdf file as a list of dataframes
        for tbl in tables:
            try:
                if(('Shoe name' in tbl.values) and ('Package size' in tbl.values)): #sometimes there are tables with just shoename so I want to make sure the table has both these fields
                    tbl.columns= ['ColA', 'ColB'] # the tables will always have just two columns. I name them ColA and ColB
                    tbl.loc[tbl.index.max() + 1] = ['ShoeCode',  bfr] #ShoeCode is not mentioned in the tables in the report - I add it to dataframe from the folder name
                    tbl.loc[tbl.index.max() + 1] = ['ShoeLink',  pdffile] #sameway i store the filepath 
                    dbase = dbase.merge(tbl,how='left', on='ColA') # once the right table is found, merge it to the dbase dataframe
                    print(bfr) #these are only to see whats happening during development - I will remove later
                    print('\n')
                    print('Final BFR Datbase: \n', dbase)
            except:
                continue
    except:
        print('Couldnt read ', bfr,'/', file[0], '\n') #if tabula reading pdf fails - take note, print message and continue
        unreadcount+=1
        unreadlist.append(bfr + '/' + file[0])
        continue
dbase=dbase.transpose() #rotate the dataframe so that all the values are now rows
dbase.to_csv(fpath, index=False, header = False) #write this to a csv file
```

Comment: A good first step would be to run a profiler on your code (https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) to find out which lines are taking the longest